# setCallback is not getting called from helper method lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

I am implementing a Jquery range slider in salesforce lightning. The issue happening is setCallback is not being called in helper method

If i am calling the below line out of the stop jquery function, i am getting the results.But if i am calling inside stop jquery function, setCallback  is not getting called.

```
helper.helperMethod(component,value);
```

Can anyone point me the correct direction how to resolve the issue.

Below is my code -

Component -

```
<aura:component controller="SimpleAccountController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,FORCE:HASRECORDID">

    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jQuery + '/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.myAction}"/>
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jQuery + '/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.myAction}"/>
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.jQuery + '/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css'}"/>
   <!-- <div id="afterLoad">Old value</div> -->
     <aura:attribute name="amount" type="decimal" />
    <style>
        #container {
        width: 100%;
        border: 68px solid gray;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="container">
     <div id="slider"/><br/>  
         <!--Slider Output here-->  
         <div id="disp"/>
        <input id="idInputHidden" type="hidden"></input>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller -

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {

     $ = jQuery.noConflict();
               $(function(){  
          createSlider('slider','disp','idInputHidden',0,0,1000);  
       });

       function createSlider(destination,dispOutput,idInputHidden,startVal,minVal,maxVal){  
           $("#"+destination).slider({   
             range: false,   
             min: minVal,  
             max: maxVal,  
             values: [startVal],  
             slide: function(event, ui){   
               $("[id$="+idInputHidden+"]").val(ui.values[0]);  
               $("#"+dispOutput).html('$' + ui.values[0]);  
             },
             stop: function (event,ui)
               {
                   var value =$("[id$="+idInputHidden+"]").val();
                   alert(value);
                   helper.helperMethod(component,value);
               },
           });
           $("#"+dispOutput).html('$' + startVal);  
         }
    },
    stopcallmethod : function(component,value) {

        alert(value);


    }
})
```

Helper -

```
({
    helperMethod : function(component,item) {
        alert(item);
        var action1 = component.get("c.getOpportunity");
        alert(action1);
        action1.setParams({"sSliderField" : item});
       action1.setCallback(this,function(response){console.log(response.getState());console.log(response.getReturnValue());});
        $A.enqueueAction(action1);

    }
})
```

Comment: Wrap  inside $A.getcallback

Comment: Hi vignesh.. i didnt get .. Can u explain me bit further..

Comment: please refer to [Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm), you should at the very least be validating the state of the response. This is basic troubleshooting. that aside, I would strongly recommend you change your helperMethod name to something more representative.

Comment: @user2542963 I updated the answer I dint tried now .Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Whenrever server trips occoured you want to use `getCallback` function when the method is called from plugin(Note: without use of `getCallback`   a   Method will call Normally without any conflicts with no server action) because  `$A.getCallback()` call ensures that the framework rerenders the modified component and processes any enqueued actions.

**Example**:

```
 stop: $A.getCallback(function ()
                   {
                       var value =$("[id$="+idInputHidden+"]").val();
                       alert(value);
                       helper.helperMethod(component,value);
                   }),
```